# Should I always trust W0613 pylint warnings in Django, especially for functions which have **kwargs as parameters?

Tags: django, python-3.6, pylint

Using Pylint on Django code, I frequently get the W0613 warning. 90% of the time the cases are relevant, when the variable is declared and not used. But sometimes I think it's not.

`W0613: Unused argument 'kwargs' (unused-argument)`

Example that triggers the warning, a view that handles the 500 error:

```
def error_500(request, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    A 500 error handling view
    '''
    data = {}
    return render(request, '500.html', data)
```

In the above case if we remove **kwargs, starting by Django 2 (as I remember), any 500 error situation leads to an unhandled exception which turns into a crash.

So I am confused if Pylint really understands all the situations that can appear or not.

**Should I always treat the warning as a real warning because my code lacks something, or should I know these exceptional cases and to silence the warning?**

I noticed that by using the special Pylint for Django this type of warning usually doesn’t appear as often (pylint-django).

But it still occurs sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a real warning- you DONT use the argument. Also, you can't remove it- you are implementing an interface that expects the argument to be there (although YOU don't use it, someone else may).

Fortunately, pylint expects this and has a setting for ignored args...

ignored-argument-names=arg|args|kwargs

These names are ones that are put in to implement an interface but you may not actually need, so ignoring that specific warning makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method expected to be overwritten by subclasses:

```
def my(arg1):
    return None
```

.. you can get around "W0613: Unused argument 'arg1' (unused-argument)" by raising an exception instead:

```
def my(arg1):
    raise NotImplementedError()
```